# How to use Bioproject ID, for example, PRJNA12997, in biopython?

Tags: sequence, bioinformatics, biopython, ncbi

I have an Excel file in which are given more then 2000 organisms, where each one of them has a Bioproject ID associated (like PRJNA12997). The idea is to use these IDs to get the sequence for a later multiple alignment with other five sequences that I have in a text file.

Can anyone help me understand how I can do this using biopython? At least the part with the bioproject ID.

Comment: Might be more relevant at: https://www.biostars.org/

Answer (score 4):

You can first get the info using `Bio.Entrez`:

```
from Bio import Entrez
Entrez.email = "Your.Name.Here@example.org"

# This call to efetch fails sometimes with a 400 error.
handle = Entrez.efetch(db="bioproject", id="PRJNA12997")
```

I've been trying, and `Entrez.read(handle)` doesn't seems to work. But if you do `record_xml = handle.read()` you'll get the XML entry for this record. In this XML you can get the ID for the organism, in this case `12997`.

```
handle = Entrez.esearch(db="nuccore", term="12997[BioProject]")
search_results = Entrez.read(handle)
```

Now you can `efecth` from your search results. At this point you should use Biopython to parse whatever you will get in the efetch step, playing with the rettype http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK25499/table/chapter4.T._valid_values_of__retmode_and/

```
for result in search_results["IdList"]:
    entry = Entrez.efetch(db="nuccore", id=result, rettype="fasta")
    this_seq_in_fasta = entry.read()
```

Comment: It seems the NCBI isn't following the typical XML style used elsewhere in Entrez, which upsets the Biopython Entrez parser. You could use something like ElementTree from the Python standard library instead. See also https://github.com/biopython/biopython/issues/805